# Swift using Nuke framework to load multiple images to an array

Tags: swift

As the question, I am using the [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) image loading and caching framework to download images from firebase, I was wondering can I load the images into an array by using this method from the framework.

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: imageView)
```

Have anyone done this before?

Comment: "Nuke" tag is for The Foundry NUKE compositing application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to download several images into an UIImage array ?